# Cheapest single board computer which can run Linux?

Tags: linux, embedded

I'm searching for the cheapest single board computer which can run Linux.  It must have ethernet and at least one serial port.

I'm currently looking at these modules from Technologic Systems, but wondering if there's anything cheaper out there?

http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=TS-7400

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Questions about shopping recommendations are considered off topic on Super User.

Comment: Seems kinda rude to the poor guy to have his question migrated here for being off topic to SO, and then closed by you guys. Where do you suggest he ask for recommendations anyway?

Comment: Seems to me it should be pushed back to SO and made CW, but I don't have the rep to affect anything here. Especially since his embedded tag almost certainly indicates he's trying to find a platform for an embedded project, which really should have been on-topic on SO in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

About the same price, but might be a bit more interesting: http://www.plugcomputer.org/

Comment: It's interesting, but I don't think they come with a serial port...but I am interested enough to look at buying one :)

Comment: The Marvell CPU has at least one UART, which IIRC is brought out by wiring it to an FTDI serial to USB chip so that you can see the serial console on a PC. A second port on the FTDI chip is setup for the on chip debugger and can be used with OpenOCD.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the list of [motherboards that run Linux](http://opencircuits.com/Motherboards_that_run_Linux)?